# get the sum of individual JSON object values in a array jquery

Tags: jquery

This is my response data format

```
{
    "data":[
        {"name":"RVCE","computers_with_multimedia":45,"computers_without_multimedia":10},
        {"name":"VITS","computers_with_multimedia":50,"computers_without_multimedia":20},
        {"name":"PMC","computers_with_multimedia":75,"computers_without_multimedia":4},
        {"name":"PCET","computers_with_multimedia":25,"computers_without_multimedia":25}
    ]
}
```

i need it in a way like
sum of obj 1 - (45+10 = 55, obj 2 - 70 and so on...

```
var count = objResponseData.data.length;
            alert("Length is " + count);
            for (intIncrement = 0; intIncrement <= count; intIncrement++) {
                var intIndividualSeating = 0;
                intIndividualSeating = parseInt(objResponseData.data[0].computers_with_multimedia) + parseInt(objResponseData.data[0].computers_without_multimedia);
            }
            alert("Individual Seating " + parseInt(intIndividualSeating));
```

Comment: What exactly is your expected output? The sum of all of the `computers...` total?

Comment: @CertainPerformance, Exactly, sum of all computers for that particular object, i think i have mentioned clearly next to my response data code.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to go with foreach loop of javascript like below

```
// here i supposed you have that object objResponseData and data is array
objResponseData.data.forEach(function(obj,index) {
   sum = obj.computers_with_multimedia + computers_without_multimedia;
   // you can also assign the value by adding these two values
   objResponseData.data[index]["sum"] = sum;
  console.log("Sum :"+sum+", assigned value to object :"+objResponseData.data[index]["sum"]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

write `objResponseData.data[intIncrement]` instead of `objResponseData.data[0]` and `console` or `alert` inside `for loop`

loop for `<count` instead of `<=count` its work

```js
var objResponseData = {
  "data": [{
      "name": "RVCE",
      "computers_with_multimedia": 45,
      "computers_without_multimedia": 10
    },
    {
      "name": "VITS",
      "computers_with_multimedia": 50,
      "computers_without_multimedia": 20
    },
    {
      "name": "PMC",
      "computers_with_multimedia": 75,
      "computers_without_multimedia": 4
    },
    {
      "name": "PCET",
      "computers_with_multimedia": 25,
      "computers_without_multimedia": 25
    }
  ]
};
//console.log(objResponseData);

var count = objResponseData.data.length;
alert("Length is " + count);
for (intIncrement = 0; intIncrement < count; intIncrement++) {
  var intIndividualSeating = 0;
  intIndividualSeating = parseInt(objResponseData.data[intIncrement].computers_with_multimedia) + parseInt(objResponseData.data[intIncrement].computers_without_multimedia);
  console.log(("Individual Seating " + parseInt(intIndividualSeating)));
}
//alert("Individual Seating " + parseInt(intIndividualSeating));
```